# Why am I unable to use prepared statements to update a database?

Tags: java, postgresql

Consider the following code:

```
String updatestmt = "UPDATE marketplaces.amazon_merchant_fulfilled_orders SET order_status = ? WHERE amazon_order_id=?;";

 Connection conn = connectToDatabase();
 PreparedStatement pstInsert = conn.prepareStatement(updatestmt);
 pstInsert.setString(1, orderId);
 pstInsert.setString(2, status);
 try {
     int rowsAffected = pstInsert.executeUpdate();
     System.out.println("Updated " + rowsAffected + " Line(s).");
 ...
```

When this code is executed, `rowsAffected` is always `0`.

If I change updatestmt to :

`"UPDATE marketplaces.amazon_merchant_fulfilled_orders SET order_status = '"+status+"' WHERE amazon_order_id='"+orderId+"';";` and remove the `pstInsert.setString` calls the code works fine.

My question is **why am I unable to use prepared statements to update my database?**

Platform: PostgreSQL 9.2 and Java 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the parameters in wrong order. Note:

```
UPDATE marketplaces.amazon_merchant_fulfilled_orders
SET order_status = ? WHERE amazon_order_id=?
```

And you're sending

```
pstInsert.setString(1, orderId);
pstInsert.setString(2, status);
```

Change the order to make it work

```
pstInsert.setString(1, status);
pstInsert.setString(2, orderId);
```

Comment: Wow - can't believe I missed that one.